# Loop through all selected sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I search for a a person's code in column "B", return the offset of the column in column "D" and replace the value of the cell with a new input.

I need to do it across all selected sheets. When I select several sheets it just executes the code on the first sheet.

[image: screenshot of the sheet]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kdol7qnfgstSc0mWV5hN9X0O1PcVwsjx/view?usp=sharing

```vb
Sub RunCode()
    Dim rg As Range, c As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set rg = ActiveSheet.Columns("B")
    str = "PEC-00" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="ID: ")
    A = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="New Value: ")
    With rg
        Set c = .Find(str, , xlValues)
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
            ws.Select       
            c.Offset(, 2) = A
        Next ws
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you set `rg` outside the loop

Comment: can you please elaborate more, do you mean i have to get the rg inside the loop? and if so how please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub RunCode()
    Dim rg As Range, c As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    str = "PEC-00" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="ID: ")
    A = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="New Value: ")
        
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        Set rg = ws.Columns("B")
        Set c = rg.Find(str, , xlValues)
        c.Offset(, 2) = A
    Next ws
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: this is untested

Comment: it gave me an eror "cannot make changes to a table or xml" becaue the tables in each sheet are dynamic tables, the code must select the tab and execute the code then go to the next tab after ungrouping them.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kdol7qnfgstSc0mWV5hN9X0O1PcVwsjx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it worked after i added ws.select in the loop